# php- how to insert form input in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that asks for comma separated phone numbers, for example, if user enters following in "Phone" field:

```
9999999999,8888800000,7777788888
```

Then want to store them as an array just like:

```
$contacts = array ("9999999999","8888800000","7777788888");
```

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
$contacts = array();
if (is_array(@$_POST['phone']))
{
    foreach($_POST['phone'] as $one)
    {
        $contacts[] = basename($one);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not difficult at all. What did you try?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+convert+comma+separated+string+to+array

Answer (score 2):

```
$myArray = explode(',', '9999999999,8888800000,7777788888');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fetch the form input with the global variable called $_POST, $_POST listens to the name of the html element.
Let's say we got

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="phoneNumber1" />
  <input type="text" name="phoneNumber2" />
  <input type="text" name="phoneNumber3" />
</form>
```

Then we are able to fetch the data in it like this.

```
$contacts = array($_POST['phoneNumber1'], $_POST['phoneNumber2'], $_POST['phoneNumber3']);
```